# How to use Dask Pivot_table?

Tags: dataframe, pivot-table, dask

I'm Trying to use Pivot_table on Dask with the following dataframe:

```
    date    store_nbr   item_nbr    unit_sales  year    month
0   2013-01-01  25       103665      7.0        2013      1
1   2013-01-01  25       105574      1.0        2013      1
2   2013-01-01  25       105575      2.0        2013      1
3   2013-01-01  25       108079      1.0        2013      1
4   2013-01-01  25       108701      1.0        2013      1
```

When I try to pivot_table as follows:

```
ddf.pivot_table(values='unit_sales', index={'store_nbr','item_nbr'}, 
                                  columns={'year','month'}, aggfunc={'mean','sum'})
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: 'index' must be the name of an existing column
```

And If I just use only one value on index and columns parameters as follows:

```
df.pivot_table(values='unit_sales', index='store_nbr', 
                                  columns='year', aggfunc={'sum'})
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: 'columns' must be category dtype
```

Answer (score 14):

That error is telling you that dask dataframe expects the column used in the columns keyword to be a categorical dtype.  It needs this so that it can define the columns correctly, even during lazy operation.  You can accomplish this as follows:

```
df = df.categorize(columns=['year'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use multiple columns and also multiple index to pivot?

Comment: When I do that, it returns me this error: `/home/miguel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/categorical.py:24: RuntimeWarning: None of the categories were found in values. Did you mean to use
'Categorical.from_codes(codes, categories)'?
  df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=vals, ordered=False)`

Comment: @Ambigus9 Seems like I can't use multiple indexes either but you can group/concat your desired columns together to be an index...

Comment: Yeah, no, it is not working. Even with `categorize` I get the same error.

Comment: Do I have to convert the dask `ddf` first to a pandas `df`? That seems inefficient.